# Proof that if columns of an square matrix  are linearly independent, the matrix  is invertible

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inverse

I understand that if the columns of a $x \times n$ square matrix $A$ are linearly independent. Then we can construct a vector $x$, such that $Ax = e_i$, $e_i$ is a unit basis. Thus we can construct a matrix $X$, such that $A X = [e_1, e_2, \cdots, e_n] = I$. However, to prove the matrix $A$ is invertible, we also need to have $X A = I$. And i don't know how to prove $X A = I$. Thanks.

===============

To be more specific, I want to prove the following claims. Suppose $A=[a_{11}, a_{12}, \dots, a_{1n}; a_{21}, a_{22}, \dots, a_{2n}; \dots; a_{m1}, a_{m2}, \dots, a_{mn}]$, and matrix $X$ in the same struct, and we know that

$
\sum_{i = 1}^n a_{ji} x_{ik} = 1, \text{if} \quad j = k 
$

$
\sum_{i = 1}^n a_{ji} x_{ik} = 0, \text{if} \quad j \neq k
$

And we are going to show that

$
\sum_{i = 1}^n x_{ji} a_{ik}  = 1, \text{if} \quad j = k
$

$
\sum_{i = 1}^n x_{ji} a_{ik} = 0, \text{if} \quad j \neq k
$

Any idea about how to prove this?

Comment: You can see this by considering the row reduction of $[A|I]$ to $[I|X)$. If you look at it upside-down, it tells you that $XA=I$.  Alternatively, you can interpret these row operations as multiplying by elementary matrices $E_1,\dots,E_k$. If $E=E_1\cdots E_k$, then $EA=I$ tells you that $A=E^{-1}$ and you're done.

Comment: @TedShifrin Thanks for your explanation, i understand from your construction, $EA = I$, but then how can we know $A E_1 \cdots E_k = I$, since $A E_1 \cdots E_k = I$ the column operation.

Comment: Because you multiply the equation by $E^{-1}$, as I said. Once you know $A=E^{-1}$ it follows that $AE=EA=I$.

Answer (score 1):

We know that If a linear map $L$ is invertible ,$\text{Ker}(L)={0} 
$
Let $L: R^n \to R^n $ $L(v)=Av$  and $ v=\begin{pmatrix} 
x_1 \\ \vdots \\ x_n \end{pmatrix}$

Let E_k be a k th row of A

$Av=x_1E_1+...+x_nE_n $  also note that

Av=0 $\Rightarrow $ v=0

v=0 $\Rightarrow $ $x_1=...=x_n =0$ which means  $E_1,...,E_n$ are linearly independent

You can prove other direction with similar way